# Простой текст в opengl в обход GLUT

Tags: opengl, текст

Хочу текст в своих "программках" выводить. Отображать текст на экране,  время, очки, таймер, простые сообщения и даже возможно "кнопочки" и т.д.

*Но **GLUT** у меня не установлен (и не установиться ;_; ибо он мракобес).*

Что делать как быть ???

Comment: https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf

Comment: Это может быть Вам интересно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод в общем-то прост. Есть две библиотеки (в одной переменные точённы в другой ....)  [SDL_ttf](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/index.html) и [SDL_gfx](http://www.ferzkopp.net/wordpress/2016/01/02/sdl_gfx-sdl2_gfx/)

---

В общем запустить я  смог только **SDL_ttf**

вот код :

**.pro**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lOpenGL

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lGLEW

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GL

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lglfw

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/GLFW

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lSDL2

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/SDL2
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../usr/include/SDL2

unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lSDL2_ttf

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/SDL2
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/SDL2

#unix:!macx: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../../usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ -lSDL2_gfx

#INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/SDL2
#DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/SDL2
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>

#include <iostream>

// Setup
bool InitEverything();
bool InitSDL();
bool CreateWindow();
bool CreateRenderer();
void SetupRenderer();

// Our new function for setting uo SDL_TTF
bool SetupTTF( const std::string &fontName );
SDL_Texture* SurfaceToTexture( SDL_Surface* surf );
void CreateTextTextures();

// Update ( happens every frame )
void Render();
void RunGame();

// Stuff for text rendering
TTF_Font* font;
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 255, 255, 255 }; // white
SDL_Color backgroundColor = { 0, 0, 0, 255 }; // black

SDL_Texture* solidTexture;
SDL_Texture* blendedTexture;
SDL_Texture* shadedTexture;

SDL_Rect solidRect;
SDL_Rect blendedRect;
SDL_Rect shadedRect;

SDL_Rect windowRect = { 900, 300, 400, 400 };
SDL_Window* window;
SDL_Renderer* renderer;

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    if ( !InitEverything() )
        return -1;

    RunGame();

        // Clean up font
        TTF_CloseFont( font );
}
void RunGame()
{
    Render();
    std::cout << "Press any key to exit\n";
    std::cin.ignore();
}
void Render()
{
    // Clear the window and make it all red
    SDL_RenderClear( renderer );

    // Render our text objects ( like normal )
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, solidTexture, nullptr, &solidRect );
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, blendedTexture, nullptr, &blendedRect );
    SDL_RenderCopy( renderer, shadedTexture, nullptr, &shadedRect );

    // Render the changes above
    SDL_RenderPresent( renderer);
}
// Initialization ++
// ==================================================================
bool SetupTTF( const std::string &fontName)
{
    // SDL2_TTF needs to be initialized just like SDL2
    if ( TTF_Init() == -1 )
    {
        std::cout << " Failed to initialize TTF : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    // Load our fonts, with a huge size
    font = TTF_OpenFont( fontName.c_str(), 90 );

    // Error check
    if ( font == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << " Failed to load font : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
void CreateTextTextures()
{
    SDL_Surface* solid = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, "solid", textColor );
    solidTexture = SurfaceToTexture( solid );

    SDL_QueryTexture( solidTexture, NULL, NULL, &solidRect.w, &solidRect.h );
    solidRect.x = 0;
    solidRect.y = 0;

    SDL_Surface* blended = TTF_RenderText_Blended( font, "blended", textColor );
    blendedTexture = SurfaceToTexture( blended );

    SDL_QueryTexture( blendedTexture, NULL, NULL, &blendedRect.w, &blendedRect.h );
    blendedRect.x = 0;
    blendedRect.y = solidRect.y + solidRect.h +  20;

    SDL_Surface* shaded = TTF_RenderText_Shaded( font, "shaded", textColor, backgroundColor );
    shadedTexture = SurfaceToTexture( shaded );

    SDL_QueryTexture( shadedTexture , NULL, NULL, &shadedRect.w, &shadedRect.h );
    shadedRect.x = 0;
    shadedRect.y = blendedRect.y + blendedRect.h + 20;
}
// Convert an SDL_Surface to SDL_Texture. We've done this before, so I'll keep it short
SDL_Texture* SurfaceToTexture( SDL_Surface* surf )
{
    SDL_Texture* text;

    text = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface( renderer, surf );

    SDL_FreeSurface( surf );

    return text;
}
bool InitEverything()
{
    if ( !InitSDL() )
        return false;

    if ( !CreateWindow() )
        return false;

    if ( !CreateRenderer() )
        return false;

    SetupRenderer();

    if ( !SetupTTF( "sketchy.ttf" ) )
        return false;

    CreateTextTextures();

    return true;
}
bool InitSDL()
{
    if ( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING ) == -1 )
    {
        std::cout << " Failed to initialize SDL : " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
bool CreateWindow()
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow( "Server", windowRect.x, windowRect.y, windowRect.w, windowRect.h, 0 );

    if ( window == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window : " << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
bool CreateRenderer()
{
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer( window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED );

    if ( renderer == nullptr )
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create renderer : " << SDL_GetError();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
void SetupRenderer()
{
    // Set size of renderer to the same as window
    SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize( renderer, windowRect.w, windowRect.h );

    // Set color of renderer to red
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor( renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255 );
}
```

Файл `sketchy.ttf` лежит в самой директории проекта.

Вот результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Осталось только научиться вставлять в свой проекты такой текстус :3 и заживем :3*